# Is there a way to add bulk media upload in the modal dialog when using ckeditor and entity embed?

Tags: media, 9

I was a heavy D7 developer and I skipped 8. Now I'm trying to build some sites in 9. Just wrapping my head around what's in core and contrib to get what I need. I was wondering what methods people are using (if any) for the possibility of doing bulk media uploads in the modal dialog in ckeditor using entity embed?

Answer (score 0):

Gotta love the downvotes for a basic question. I sure missed you, Drupal community.

I'll answer my own question then.

https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser

> This module provides a default Entity Browser that lets you browse and select your files in a nice-looking, mobile-ready Masonry based interface, and upload files using the Dropzonejs module.